# LibreOffice 4.3 does not convert to PDF (command line), but no errors reported

Tags: pdf, fedora, libreoffice

We are running Fedora on a dedicated server:

```
Linux host.**obscured**.<tld> 2.6.18-348.6.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue May 21
15:29:55 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

One important aspect of our web application is the ability to upload all types of documents, such as Open Office or Microsoft, and convert them dynamically to PDF, so they can be displayed on the site, and also using a JPG thumbnail created from the PDF asset.

Until recently, this function worked great, using LibreOffice 4.0.  We used the soffice binary to dynamically convert uploaded files in a background shell command.

Then suddenly, LibreOffice stopped working, and we could not restore it, so we downloaded and installed LibreOffice 4.3.

The program now works, in the sense that it no longer bombs when forking off a the process, but the conversion no longer works, and doesn't produce any output or errors:

We essentially use the same syntax as from LibreOffice 4.0, which used to work correctly:

```
/opt/libreoffice4.3/program/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --nofirststartwizard 
--outdir **obscured** --nofirststartwizard  **obscured**.docx
```

(I have obscured certain information here, intentionally, for the privacy of our users)

Again, this same syntax used to work with LibreOffice 4.0, until it broke, presumably due to an update of Java JRE on the server  (we're not 100% sure...)

I cross-checked the syntax against online resources.

There was also mention of not being able to convert when another LibreOffice instance is running, and I checked that this was the only process!

Any thoughts or ideas will be appreciated, as this function is an important part of the application user experience

Comment: check `libreoffice --headless --convert-to  ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, after I 've used strace , I could see that fonts are missing.

http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/30069/pdf-font-embedding-in-libreoffice-42/